# Finding the volume of a solid by revolving around the x-axis

Tags: integration

Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region bound by y=1/sqrt(x) and y=0 for 1 ≤ x ≤ 2 about the line y=-1. 
I did

V = ∫ 2π(-1−y)(1-(1/y^2)dy, where a = -1 and b = 1

But integrating that integral gives me infinity, which doesn't seem right. Am I missing something? 
 Thanks, 
Cam